# Android R file constants not auto-updating

Tags: android, constants, r.java-file

I've searched high and low for people with the same question but have only found some variations (i.e. R file not generated at all) that don't help. I'm VERY new to Android development (day one, actually) but from some tutorials I've been reading, this behavior is unexpected. Basically, let's say I create a TextView in my activity's XML file and give it an appropriate android:id. I save the file (and all other files), but if I try to use findViewById in my Java file, the R.id.[view name] is not listed (and displays an error if I manually type it in). If I do a "Build Project," it works, but to have to run the Build command upon creation of every new component will be a huge burden! Has anyone else experienced this or have ideas on why it's happening? Thanks in advance!

Comment: What IDE are you using? You may have to tell it to build automatically. For example, in Eclipse this would be: `Window > Preferences > General > Workspace > Build automatically`.

Comment: Wow...I feel like an idiot. I swear I looked through all the preferences and looked for a "Build automatically" check box. This was the only issue! Thanks so much!

Comment: Posted it as an answer so the question can be closed.

Answer (score 0):

If everything else you mentioned is correct, then the only way for you to NOT get the proper R variables is that you might be importing "android.R;" file in stead of your actual R file "your.package.R" which contains the variables you are looking for.

Regards!

Comment: I'm not importing any R file at all (I've read that you should never directly import a generated file). I'm just confused as to why I need to rebuild the project in order for the R file to update with new constants. Nothing else in my project changes so I'm assuming the R file is simply not updating in real time upon creation of new variables. Looking at my Java file before and after a "Build Project" shows that absolutely nothing changed, except now findViewById(R.id.[whatever]) doesn't show an error.

Answer (score 0):

You may have to tell your IDE to automatically rebuild changes you make. For example, in Eclipse this would be in: `Window > Preferences > General > Workspace`. Make sure `Build automatically` is checked.